# Login Page redirecting to admin.php but not connecting to adminpanel.php

Tags: php, sql, database

Here is how my admin login page should work:

1.For a valid login: 
login.php>admin.php>adminpanel.php
2. For non valid login: 
login.php>admin.php>login.php

Facts:
1. db is connected 
2. db fields are "userid" "username" "  password"
3. password is encrypted

Problem is :
Login page redirecting me to admin.php page and no error is showing .

```html
 //login.php

 <form action = "admin.php" role="form" method="post">
   <div class="form-group input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Super Admin Name">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Password</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Super Admin Password">
  </div>
  <?php 
  if (isset($_GET['error'])){
  echo "Hay Dude!!! Are You Lost? call 911!!";
  }?>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">login</button>
</form>   

 //admin.php
<?php
include ("dbconnect.php");
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['logout'])){
   unset($_session['admin']);
}
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
$login_sqli= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Name ='".$_POST['username']."'AND Password='".sha1($_POST['password'])."'";
$login_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$login_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($login_query)>0){

$login_rs= mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_query);
$_session['admin']=$login_rs['username'];


}else 
header ("location:admin.php?error=login");
}
<body>
   <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">


 <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Hay Dude! You Lost?? Try Again or Call 911!!</h1>


<?php
if (!isset($_session['admin'])){

include ("login.php");
}else{

include ("adminpanel.php");

}

?>


                </div>
 </div>


</body>
```

Comment: `name` attribute is missing from your `<input>` and `<button>` fields.

Comment: what is your point of using ? : header ("location:admin.php?error=login");

Comment: You are including login.php and adminpanel.php in your admin.php. So you should always navigate to admin.php? Also, please mind SQL Injection. The passwordfield is not protected. And the check whether or not it is an admin, is not really secure. Just some things to keep in mind.

Comment: if its not loged in it will show on url ... @Soheyl

Comment: And what happen next ?

Comment: @Soheyl he is trying to output an error (as seen in the HTML form) when the URL param `error` is set. So thats why he uses `header ("location:admin.php?error=login");` after a fault.

Comment: As I understood, your code will not work as you expected !

Because :

When you run your code, if your login is success, you create a session and you want to include *adminpanle*, you need to refresh the page to check the session !

Comment: Also as far as i understand his code does not work as he describes. It seems to me this is a one page application, by including the login.php and adminpanel.php in his admin.php. He is describing his program flow as visiting login.php, posting to admin.php and then getting redirected to adminpanel.php OR login.php depending on the success of the login attempt.